# How to remove duplicated concatenated string in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
    path     value
1 b,b,a,c     3
2     c,b     2
3       a    10
4 b,c,a,b     0
5     e,f     0
6     a,f     1
```

## df

```
df <- data.frame (path= c("b,b,a,c", "c,b", "a", "b,c,a,b" ,"e,f" ,"a,f"), value = c(3,2,10,0,0,1))
```

and I wish to remove duplicated in column path.  when I use this code the format of data changes:

```
df$path  <-  sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path), split=","),
                                   function(x) unique(x))
```

and it gives me data like a dataframe

```
    path             value
1 c("b", "a", "c")     3
2 c( "c", "b ")       2
...
```

However, I wish to have data like that:

```
 path value
1 b, a, c     3
2    c, b     2
3       a    10
4 b, c, a     0
5    e, f     0
6    a, f     1
```

Comment: You can actually leave it as a list column if you use `lapply` instead of `sapply`, which may be more useful in the long run: `df$path <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path), ','), unique)` and happens to be printed the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `unique(x)` with `paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')`, or `toString(unique(x))` as Frank suggested.

```
df <- data.frame (
    path= c("b,b,a,c", "c,b", "a", "b,c,a,b" ,"e,f" ,"a,f"),
    value = c(3,2,10,0,0,1))

df$path  <-  sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path), split=","),
                    function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ', '))

# or
df$path  <-  sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$path), split=","),
                    function(x) toString(unique(x)))

df
#      path value
# 1 b, a, c     3
# 2    c, b     2
# 3       a    10
# 4 b, c, a     0
# 5    e, f     0
# 6    a, f     1
```

Comment: That `paste(z, collapse=", ")` works like `toString(z)` here, I think.

Comment: wow, I never know this function before! It is very convenient.

Comment: @MFR, I added my output, it is exactly what you want. did you update the `df` after you changed it?

Comment: You are welcome. I also learned something new from this post.

Comment: @alistaire, I made the edit following your suggestion.